# picture over intrinsic image size

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

I am trying to improve my page using picture html5 element.

When i am use default img tag it will sizing by intrinsic size default.
But when i am use picture size it will sizing over intrinsic size.

How can i fix that?

[over intrinsic size picture tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdB9x.png)

[image: default equal intrinsic size]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was i dont mark the size attribute on source tag,so browsers have no any information about image width